# Rails Delayed Jobs NoMethodError: Undefined Method `prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asynchronous, delayed-job

I am getting this error for a delayed job on a class method:

```
FAILED (0 prior attempts) with NoMethodError: undefined method `prefix' for #<Object:0x007f9801e1d548>
```

This is the async method:

```
class << self
    def new_request(users, api_client)
      api_client.create_async_call({
        subject: 'subject',
        body: 'body',
        recipients: [user1, user2...]
      })
    end
    handle_asynchronously :new_request
end
```

And I'm calling the method this way:

```
Notification.new_catalog_request(users, api_client)
```

I've looked at the README file on delayed jobs and looked at the other stackoverflow answers and none of them have worked.

What do I need to do to get this async job to run?

Comment: Which line of code seems to be generating that error message?

Comment: @MarsAtomic - `handle_asynchronously` seems to be the problem. The function works great with out making it async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The odds are your api_client isn't being properly serialized and de-serialized in the job.  You might have better luck passing in the necessary data, and re-instantiating the api_client object from within the job instead of depending on the serialized version.

Comment: I come from a java background and Java definitely wins in the async arena